# Chained Promises (Q deferred) with Object / Prototype

Tags: javascript, closures, prototype, promise

I have a simple Javascript (Node) object, which has a function that sets a property on the object and returns a promise.

Note, for this example I've removed the actual async call that needs to be deferred, as it doesn't effect the outcome.

```
var q = require("Q");

var Foo = function(){
  this.bar = false;
  return this;
};

Foo.prototype.set = function(){
  var d = q.defer();
  this.bar = true; 
  d.resolve();
  return d.promise;
};

Foo.prototype.check = function(){
  var d = q.defer();
  console.log(this.bar);
  d.resolve();
  return d.promise;
};
```

When the above is called in a promise-defeating way like below, this.bar is true (as expected).

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.set().then(function(){
  foo.check();
});
```

However, when it's called in a chain, it's undefined:

```
foo.set().then(foo.check);
```

I'm curious to understand what's causing this. My best guess is a closure issue with the way that my object's methods are chained together.

In most cases, I'd pass the value to resolve/reject and go from there. In this case, I want to run some data through a series of sequential functions (some requiring deferment). Rather than passing the output to each function in the chain, I want to store and update the data in the object itself.

Any clarity would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try `foo.set().then(foo.check.bind(foo));`

Comment: I added it as an answer :-) no problem you are welcome

Comment: It's worth mentioning that other libraries (like bluebird) or if you can use ES6 (ala babeljs) this gets _way_ nicer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you calls callback without context and `this` is just global object

As a solution you need to bind context like this

```
foo.set().then(foo.check.bind(foo));
```